# Optimizing my sql query

Tags: mysql

I have created the following query to make a "frequency diagram" that displays the number of rows that are between certain values:

```
SELECT CONCAT('0 - ', M.MaxField1) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1<M.MaxField1
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*2)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*2)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*2), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*3)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*2) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*3)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*3), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*4)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*3) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*4)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*4), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*5)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*4) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*5)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*5), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*6)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*5) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*6)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*6), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*7)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*6) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*7)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*7), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*8)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*7) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*8)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*8), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*9)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*8) AND P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*9)
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*9), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*10)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M
WHERE P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*9)
```

Any suggestions to optimize this script as it is quite time consuming?

Comment: Are your histogram buckets evenly spaced and sized?

Comment: Of course they are - I just looked at the code again.

Comment: Could you provide sample data (sqlfiddle?).

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested):

```
WITH cte(MaxField1) AS (
    SELECT (MAX(Field1)/10) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1
)
SELECT 
    'Part',
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CONCAT((MaxField1*M.bucket), ' - ', (MaxField1*(M.bucket+1))) AS 'Part',
        Field1 / cte.MaxField1 AS bucket
    FROM TABLE1, cte
) AS M
GROUP BY 'Part'
```

For MySQL users, who don't have CTE expressions, try this instead:

```
SELECT 
    'Part',
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CONCAT((MaxField1*M.bucket), ' - ', (MaxField1*(M.bucket+1))) AS 'Part',
        Field1 / cte.MaxField1 AS bucket
    FROM TABLE1, 
   (SELECT (MAX(Field1)/10) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1)cte
) AS M
GROUP BY 'Part'
```

OR in Dutch:

```
SELECT 
    'Part', 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        CONCAT((MaxPercbeheer*M.bucket), ' - ', (MaxPercbeheer*(M.bucket+1))) AS 'Part', 
        (Percbeheer/cte.MaxPercbeheer) AS bucket, 
        MaxPercbeheer 
    FROM POLIS, (SELECT (MAX(Percbeheer)/10) AS MaxPercbeheer FROM POLIS) cte
) AS M 
GROUP BY 'Part'
```

Comment: It says Unknown column "bucket" in fieldlist

Comment: @The Code Buccaneer: I modified a second time. Did you catch the latest update?

Comment: Is this not a valid construct in MySQL perhaps: SELECT bucket = Field1 / cte.MaxField1? Let's reword it using AS

Comment: I have it working with the following script:
SELECT 
    CONCAT((MaxPercbeheer*M.bucket), ' - ', (MaxPercbeheer*(M.bucket+1))) AS 'Part',
    COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT (Percbeheer/cte.MaxPercbeheer) AS bucket, MaxPercbeheer
    FROM POLIS, 
   (SELECT (MAX(Percbeheer)/10) AS MaxPercbeheer FROM POLIS)cte
) AS M
GROUP BY bucket

But the buckets are not correct. There are 49 rows instead of 10

Comment: I know what I forgot. Give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

You could turn it into one query as the union parts are essentially same query:

```
create temporary table range_tmp (start int, end int);
insert into range_tmp values (0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10);

SELECT CONCAT((M.MaxField1*t.start), ' - ', (M.MaxField1*t.end)) AS 'Part',COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1 P, (SELECT (MAX(Field1)*(1/10)) AS MaxField1 FROM TABLE1) AS M, range_tmp t
WHERE (P.Field1>=(M.MaxField1*t.start) or t.start=1) AND (P.Field1<(M.MaxField1*t.end) or t.end=10)
```